# Is specific orbital energy conserved when the two bodies are charged

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, black-holes, energy-conservation, orbital-motion

I apologize if this question has already been asked before but I couldn't seem to find it anywhere.
I am currently writing a program that plots charged particles around charged blackholes (Reissner–Nordström blackholes). Using the wiki page for the Reissner–Nordström metric I have been able to plot orbits of non charged particles. However the wiki doesn't seem to include the equations of motion for charged particles. When attempting to derive them myself I find that my program is no longer conserving specific orbital energy but it is conserving specific relative angular momentum. I know from classical E&M that work either has to be done or vice versa when a charged particle moves through an electric field depending on the signs of the charges. I'm not sure if I'm confusing this work energy with something less general and less relative than specific orbital energy.

In short, should the specific orbital energy of a two body system change when both bodies are charged?

Comment: The equation of motion of a charged particle in curved spacetime is the 4th equation in [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_in_general_relativity#Extension_to_the_case_of_a_charged_particle) of Wikipedia’s article on geodesics in GR.

Comment: Thanks, seems like this wiki page uses the same equation to get the equations of motion as the Reissner–Nordström metric wiki does, that's good. However the question of the conservation of specific orbital energy doesn't seem to be mentioned in that wiki. @G.Smith

Comment: The Wikipedia article on RN holes does mention the specific energy and does say it is constant.

Comment: I don’t understand why [Wikipedia’s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner–Nordström_metric#Equations_of_motion) equations of motion for $t$, $r$, and $\theta$ don’t contain any terms with $q$. This seems wrong.

Comment: You might want to look at [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.5399) instead.

Comment: Yes, the RN metric wiki page only seems to give equations of motion for the case where q=0, that's why I had some doubt about whether E would be conserved for the case where q is non zero, and thank you, I will take a look at the paper. @G.Smith

Comment: It seems the equation of S_3 on the Reissner–Nordström metric wikipedia page should have an extra qQ/r term added . When this change is made, E is conserved. Equation 5.28 from this paper shows this clearly. https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:912393/FULLTEXT01.pdf

Comment: Yes, basically that section of Wikipedia is wrong. It’s actually the worst mistake on a Wikipedia physics page I’ve seen.

Comment: I see that you have edited the Wikipedia page. I don’t see how the new equation for $S_3$ is compatible with the existing equation for $\gamma$.  Isn’t the sign of the $qQ$ term inconsistent?

Comment: The old formula for $\gamma$ is also missing an $M$ in one of the terms in the denominator.